The idempotented algebra
Let $k$ be a field, An idempotented algebra over a field k is a k-algebra H together with a collection E of idempotents
of H satisfying the conditions:

For all $e_1, e_2 ∈ E$ there exists $e_0 ∈ E$ such that $e_0e_1=e_1e_0=e_1$ and $e_0e_2=e_2e_0=e_2$.
For all $x ∈ H$ there exists $e ∈ E$ with $ex = xe = x$.

Now, if $(H_1, E_1)$ and $(H_2,E_2)$ are both idempotented k-algebra. I want to show that $H_1\otimes_k H_2$ equipped with the set $E_1\otimes E_2:=\{e_1\otimes e_2;e_1\in E_1, e_2\in E_2\}$ is also an idempotented k-algebra.
I already check that $E_1\otimes E_2$ is a set of idempotent and satisfy the first condition.
Problems: elements in  $H_1\otimes_k H_2$ is of the form $\Sigma_i c_i(a_i\otimes b_i)$, how can I found an element $e_1\otimes e_2\in E_1\otimes E_2$ satisfies $(\Sigma_i c_i(a_i\otimes b_i))(e_1\otimes e_2)=\Sigma_i c_i(a_ie_1\otimes b_ie_2)=\Sigma_i c_i(a_i\otimes b_i)$. So, the question is can I found "an" element $e_1\otimes e_2\in E_1\otimes E_2$ such that $(a_i\otimes b_i)(e_1\otimes e_2)=(a_i\otimes b_i)$ for "all" i?

Note that elements of $H_1 \otimes_k H_2$ can be written as finite sums $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} a_i \otimes b_i$ by pushing the coefficients inside the first component. From the definition of multiplication in $H_1 \otimes_k H_2$ it suffices to consider the two algebras separately, so we need to answer the following:
Given a finite collection $a_1, \dots, a_n \in H$ find an idempotent $e \in H$ such that $e a_i = a_i = a_i e$ for all $i$.
This can be seen by induction, requiring both of the conditions on $H$. The base case is immediate. Suppose for $a_1, \dots a_{n-1}$ we have $e_1$ and for $a_n$ we have $e_2$. Take $e_0$ as in condition (1). Then $a_1 = e_1 a_1$ so
$$e_0 a_1 = e_0 e_1 a_1 = e_1 a_1 = a_1$$
and similarly for all other $a_i$.
